# How to display location of visitor?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a website for an old school friend of mine with some basic knowledge and past experience with WordPress, but there seems to be something I just can't figure out.

How would I go about displaying the location of the visitor automatically? For example, there would be text like, "Coming to a location near [City, State]" depending on where the person is using their device from.

Would I have to use java script? I'm not really familiar with writing code so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes, `javascript` and ask for the [user's geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation)

Comment: Impossible to achieve reliably regardless of the technology used. Guessing the user's location doesn't require javascript but might be useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is not really appropriate for SO, as it is very broad. SO is for *specific* problems about programming, usually with some code involved. Please have a look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) guides for more info. There are plenty of articles about geolocation - research an approach, implement it, and if you have trouble ask here about *that*, showing us what you'e already tried.